# Using a boost converter controller in an MPPT application

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, mppt

I am hoping to use a standard synchronous boost converter (LTC3786) for MPPT controlled solar panel to battery.

[image]

Nearly all applications I see make reference to adjusting the PWM DC to control input impedance.
[image]

Using a device such as the LTC3786, however, will not allow for direct PWM control as this is taken care of inside the controller.

The only way to adjust the output voltage is though the VFB pin (normally via a potential divider on the output.)

I hope to get around this by using a programmable potentiometer on the lower half of the potential divider to adjust the output voltage / input impedance as required.

I can't help but think I am missing something and this would not work.

Does anyone have any input with the potential issues I would encounter with this approach? I am aware that there are many other ways I could approach this but my requirements are driving me in this direction.

I will also need to run multiple MPPTs in parallel. I hope to combat any feedback power by the use of ideal diodes on the outputs.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Adv please post a block diagram or schematic. Also there is a circuit tool if you edit your question that can draw schematics.